# Redis doesn't work in python job with cron job in docker

Tags: python, docker, redis, cron

I am trying to run a cron job with python, celery and redis.
The docker image starts and runs fine - the cron job starts, but redis doesn't work. In the code, I took a shit debugging:

There is **docker-compose** file:

```
   version: '3'
services:
  task_runner-test:
    container_name: RunTasksTest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./runner:/app
    extra_hosts:
    - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    stdin_open: true # docker run -i
    tty: true        # docker run -t
    environment:
      - REDIS_HOST=host.docker.internal
      - REDIS_PORT=6300
      - BROKER_URL=redis://host.docker.internal:6300/0
      - RESULT_BACKEND=redis://host.docker.internal:6300/0
```

There is **dockerfile**:

```
FROM python:3.9-buster

WORKDIR app

COPY /runner .

RUN chmod 644 /app/script.sh

RUN apt-get update -y \
   && apt-get -y install cron \
   && crontab -l | { cat; echo "* * * * * bash /app/script.sh"; } | crontab - \
   && pip install --no-cache-dir celery redis loguru

# Run the command on container startup
CMD ["cron","-f"]
```

There is script who must run python script:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------" >> /app/logs/output.log;
echo "$(date) ### Aggregation process trying to start ###" >> /app/logs/output.log;
cd /app
python3 task_loader.py >> /app/logs/output.log;

echo "$(date) ### Aggregation process succesfully started ###" >> /app/logs/output.log;
echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------"  >> /app/logs/output.log;
```

My logic is in the tasks_loader.py module where I am actually trying to import Redis and Celery settings.

**task_loader.py** file:

```
import os

print('-------------------',f'task_loader starts wit workdir {os.getcwd()}','-------------------')
import tasks as t
...
print('-------------------',f'import step passed','-------------------')
```

At the beginning of the file, I tried to import the settings and print out exactly where the code left off using the print.

**tasks.py :**

```
print('-------------------',f'task mirror','-------------------')
import os
BROKER_HOST=os.getenv('REDIS_HOST')
BROKER_PORT=os.getenv('REDIS_PORT')
from redis import Redis
print('-------------------',f'trying to connect to redis','-------------------')
```

Actually in tasks.py - I'm trying to set up redis and Celery, but the output in the logs shows that Redis was not started. Here is the actual log.

```
Fri Apr 21 09:51:01 UTC 2023 ### Aggregation process trying to start ###
------------------- Requesting to celery with redis host and port -------------------
------------------- task_loader starts wit workdir /app -------------------
------------------- task mirror -------------------
Fri Apr 21 09:51:01 UTC 2023 ### Aggregation process succesfully started ###
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Apr 21 09:52:01 UTC 2023 ### Aggregation process trying to start ###
------------------- Requesting to celery with redis host and port -------------------
------------------- task_loader starts wit workdir /app -------------------
------------------- task mirror -------------------
Fri Apr 21 09:52:01 UTC 2023 ### Aggregation process succesfully started ###
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```